# What are the meanings of different Unix commands?

Tags: command-line, terminal, command

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my machine. I am feeling lost when I see different command line commands (or what exactly are they called?)  like `sudo`, `apt-get`, `mkdir`, `-R`, `-n` etc. while installing different software like Node JS, Mongo DB etc.

What are some good resources where I can find what do different Linux/Unix commands exactly mean?

Comment: Command line utilities almost always have "man(ual) pages" which you can view with `man`, e.g., `man apt-get`. **[TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/)** has lots of guides, how-tos, etc.  If you click through "Guides" and scroll down, there's an "Introduction to Linux" and "GNU/Linux Command-Line Tools Summary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man` pages are your friend. Whenever you see a command you've never used, run `man [name of command]`

For example, `man sudo` will tell you:

> NAME
>         sudo, sudoedit - execute a command as another user

and, lower down:

> DESCRIPTION
>          sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified in the sudoers file.  The real and effective uid and gid are set to
>          match those of the target user as specified in the passwd file and the group vector is initialized based on the group file (unless the -P option was specified).  If
>          the invoking user is root or if the target user is the same as the invoking user, no password is required.  Otherwise, sudo requires that users authenticate
>          themselves with a password by default (NOTE: in the default configuration this is the user's password, not the root password).  Once a user has been authenticated, a
>          time stamp is updated and the user may then use sudo without a password for a short period of time (5 minutes unless overridden in sudoers).

If the wording is too complicated, that's when you do a Google search such as "Linux what does sudo do?"

Answer (score 0):

- `sudo` stands for substitute user do
- `mkdir` stands for make directory
- `apt` stands for advanced packaging tool

The options like `-r` or `-f` are just random letters, but sometimes stands for  real stuff.

Like `-u` in ytdl stands for `update`, you can also run it using `--update` or `-h` which can also be run using `--help`

Use `man` to get information about them.